# Macro to move data from multiple sheets to 1 sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 47 sheets with the same data. I want to move the following cells from each sheet to one sheet so I can easily do an infile to SAS. The cells are:

B4, B5, B8, G13-23, I13-23, J13-23, K13-23, l13-23

Can anyone help me with a macro?

Comment: I assume you mean you have 47 sheets with the same layout, not the same data, right? Also, where do you want the data to be on the output sheet?

Comment: Yes we can help you with your macro, show us your macro and we will give you ideas of what to use for the gaps. If you just look for someone to program this for you completely I fear you misunderstood the idea of this website and suggest you to search for a freelancer somewhere else

Comment: I cannot paste the code. It is too long. The macro record does work but it means going in and changing this section:  sheets("1").select 47 times for each of the sheets and I have more folders than just this one. I am doing this with QTR 1 right now. sheets("1").select shows up 4 times in my macro so 47 * 4 means lots of time to do all this. there has to be a way to say sheets("1", "2", "3", on up to 47).select and do this at one time

Comment: If you are planning to write a macro, you might just create a csv rather than putting it into another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the Developer tab on, turn on Macro Recording, perform the action once then edit the macro to match your needs

Comment: I have 47 sheets same layout, not same data within each cell. B4 for instance has the various MPIN for the 47 various hospitals submiting the data. Cell B5 has the claim number.

Comment: That only works by editing the macro where it has Sheets("1") I have to change the sheet throughout the recorded macro and that means I have to change this 47 times. This is not the only series I have to do this for. I also have q2, q3, q4 that will each have 47-50 sheets. I might as well just copy and paste cuz that takes the same amount of time.

Comment: I want something I can create a macro so it can pull in the cells from each of the sheets with one run function

Comment: @tinaMiller put the sheet name in a variable, modify the variable per your needs. I can't see your sheet to tell you what exactly to do. Look up "VBA variables" and "VBA loops" in google.

Comment: I tried does not work. Never mind I am wasting more time tryin to figure it out than if I just copy and paste manually. I will just do that.